# awk between 2 timestamps

Tags: awk, date

New to awk
 I am trying to print only the lines from a logfile with the first field between these 2 values:

```
awk '{print $0($1 > 1300000000) && ($1 < 1305000000)}' Log2.log
```

and...its not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '1300000000 < $1 && $1 < 1305000000' Log2.log
```

Style :)

Comment: as a matter of style, I tend to write this kind of comparision like this: `a < x && x < b` -- closer to the mathematical notation

Comment: Yep, I prefer this style too.